# Motivating the use of the theory rough paths in stochastic analysis

Tags: pr.probability

I am a final year undergraduate looking to do a PhD in stochastic analysis, perhaps with applications to problems in mathematical finance. On a potential supervisor's webpage, it says that one of  his research focuses is the theory of rough paths.

I would like to get a feel for what this entails. Do any of you know of any books or articles which provide a well-motivated introduction to the theory? Or could you provide an example a problem for which this theory is useful?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask. Generally, 'tell me about ...' questions are not focused enough for MO. A google search for 'rough paths stochastic analysis' (with no quotes) found me this: http://sag.maths.ox.ac.uk/tlyons/st_flour/rough_paths_bibliography.htm where there looks to be some nice introductory articles.

Comment: In my limited understanding, Lyons is the father of rough path theory, at least in the form currently studied; so his work would seem a logical place to look. Since you say you are a final year undergraduate, you may find yourself needing some intermediary background with e.g. martingales, rigorous Brownian motion etc (or you might not; it's hard to tell). Friz http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~friz/index.html is also one of the main names, whose work might provide a road in

Comment: @Unknown : There is a very good book by Friz and Victoir "Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths: Theory and Applications" that you can google for. Regards 